# Find position of items wrapping a given value in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a vector X-values in ascending order as the following example:

```
x1 = [1, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 24, 30, 35, 46, 51, 60]
```

I would like to get the position of those values in my vector that wrap a given number, as binary list or straightforward position:

```
E.g:

Number_N = 10 --> xpos=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] // xpos=[3,4]
Number_N = 50 --> xpos=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] // xpos=[9,10]
Number_N = 1 --> xpos=[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] // xpos=[0,1]
```

I am getting a syntax error in here:

```
Xpos = [1 if (l <= num & l+1 >= num) else 0 for l in x1[0:]]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Something like this: Xpos = [1 if (l <= num & l+1 >= num) else 0 for l in x1[0:]]

Comment: Asking for someone who make your homeworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of [bisect.bisect_right](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) which finds the insertion point in a sorted collection after any existing entries of the searched value.

If `n` is our input number, then we can do the following:

```
idx = bisect.bisect_right(x1, 0)
```

and then

```
xpos = [0] * len(x1)
xpos[idx] = 1
if idx > 0:
    xpos[idx - 1] = 1
```

Comment: Yes I can work from here! I did not know the algorithm,. Thanks a lot!